# Symfony 4 deployement's rooting on apache

Tags: php, apache, symfony, symfony4, vhosts

So I have my symfony 4 app and I have to deploy it on a private server.

My private server (on debian) has already a website in var/www/html/ accessible by 'url.com' My etc/hosts file look like this:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
xxx.xx.xx.xx  url.com     url
```

I would like my symfony app to be accessible whether by 'app.url.com' or url.com/app.

I tried setting up a vhost and adding my new url to the hosts file by adding a line like this one : xxx.xx.xx.xx app.url.com.

I also tried different VHost conf file but none worked, so I must miss something.

EDIT:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.fr
    ServerAlias www.app.fr
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/app/public"
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app-access.log common


<Directory "/var/www/html/app/public">
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =app.fr
RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```

Comment: the vhost config would help. do you need dns set up too?

Comment: does "xxx.xx.." means the different server? If so then DNS entry is required :) or if it's your on your machine then just replace these xx with 127.0.0.1 I don't quite get what you need

Comment: I edited the post and added the vhost config, the xxx.xx.xx.xx is just the server IP and it's the same for both projet.

Comment: I tried starting from scratch and I'm always stuck at the same point: put my project on the server, install the dependencies, create the vhost, modify (or not) the etc/hosts file and my symfony site is not accessible neither by 'app.url.com' or 'url.com/app'

Comment: I also tried instaling the apache-pack but same thing. Is that normal that when I go to url.com/app/public I have an error 500 on my server but when I try on my local machine I have a result ?